# Outlook adding fields to appointment form

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Im at a bit of a lost. Using Outlook 2013 how does one add and show additional textboxes below the fields in the new appointment dialog.
Yes I know about Form Regions. But it adds it to the bottom of the new appointment dialog. I need to be able to add it below fields like start and end time.
Downvoters... Please. Dont for a second assume I didnt search google

Answer (score 0):

Your Task Pane can be docked to the top of the form. Just below the star/end/location fields.

Comment: Going t try now

Comment: I set my FormREgionType to Adjoining. However.. cannot dock it??

Comment: Sorry, I meant a task pane, not a form region. Set CustomTaskPane.DockPosition property to msoCTPDockPositionTop

Comment: Yeah I know. But it docks it above the fields... not below

Comment: It turns out one cannot edit that panel (with subject/from etc)My options were to either create a new form (Hell no) or Manually inject a panel into the form